# I just cant figure out the formula for this excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i hope someone can help me with a formula for excel.
On my sheet i have on column A -  D's for Dog, and C's for Cat, and O, for other.
I'm trying to figure out the formula for: If 8 or more of the last 13 entries is D, then B14=D. If 8 or more of the last 13 entries = C, then B14=C.
Otherwise O (If neither A or C has 8 or more entries)
Thanks

Comment: @bdr9 thanks heaps, work a treat, and thanks for the explanation also. I was stuck on a "if" track, and it really did my head in!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should accomplish what you are looking for.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A13, "D")>=8, "D", IF(COUNTIF(A1:A13, "C")>=8, "C", "O"))
```

It uses the `COUNTIF` function to count the number of cells in `A1:A13` that are equal to `D`. If that number is greater than or equal to 8, the result will be `D`. If not, it will use `COUNTIF` again to count the `C`'s. If this is greater than or equal to 8, `C` will be displayed, otherwise, `O`.